# Quickest way to gain access to "My Documents" in old HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a "My Documents" folder that is 600 GB large in an old HDD. If I click into it, my explorer.exe will be frozen for a whole day and still not finish setting the permissions.

I want to know what's the quickest way for me to clone that folder and/or open up all the access.

Edit: Many thanks for downvoting, guys. I was able to partially work around the issue by accessing the folder through Powershell. It seems like the disk is indeed going bad as some of you suggested, since when I tried to access some files, the disk locks up (likely why permission took forever to set).

After salvaging the most critical files, I am going to run a disk repair to see if I can recover the HDD

Comment: Can you access the folder/files using Command Prompt?

Comment: Yes. I was able to

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have problem with your OLD HDD.

1. Take advice that user @davidgo mentioned below and "make a bit copy of the drive"
2. Make a disk test of your "OLD DISK" try to fix it with utility "chkdsk" in CMD. I think that command would be needed to run for you:

   chkdsk %YOUR OLD DISK drive letter%: /F /X /R /B
3. if everything is okay you have a high probability to enter your folder
   unless there is another problem, maybe access to files like you have encrypted your folder (you did not write more details, so there is only guesses)

Comment: Yeah, seems like the drive is going bad. It's locking on some files when I tried to copy them.

Answer (score 2):

As @user1448914 said you almost certainly have a disk issue or corruption.

The first step is to make a bit copy of the drive - and then, if necessary clean the filesystem on the copy. In fact, you should not be using the old disk until you have done the copy as you could be causing worse corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an old drive. Every Windows-based recovery tool failed and was unable to completely recover the data. Then I stumbled on [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html), a Linux-based data recovery tool that worked great for me. Took a long time but in the end I had a complete image of my drive.

Here are some links and guides. I highly recommend you read through them first to be sure you know what you're doing:

https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html
https://www.technibble.com/guide-using-ddrescue-recover-data/
https://www.data-medics.com/forum/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-with-bad-sectors-using-ddrescue-t133.html